# Is there any way of describing "an object type that cannot be empty" in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-never

I have a function, and it can operate on any type `T`. The only constraint is "if `T` is an object, it can't be an object which can potentially be empty".

I tried this:

```js
declare function func<T>(o: T extends Record<string, never> ? never : T): void;

func("string")         // passes, as expected
func({})               // fails, as expected
func<{x?: number}>({}) // passes, noooo
```

Also this:

```
type EmptyObj = Omit<{x: number}, 'x'>

declare function func2<T>(o: T extends EmptyObj ? never : T): void;

func2("HI") // fails
func2({}).  // fails
func2<{x?: number}>({x: 1}) // fails, as expected
func2<{x: number}>({x: 1}) // fails
```

`func2` is probably running into the the fact `{}` is the top type, so everything extends it. Is typescript capable of describing what I need it to?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKy7yN) meet your needs?  (Please test against relevant use cases.) If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz this seems to work like I need it to! I don't understand it yet, but I'd accept it as the right answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
declare function func<T extends ({} extends T ? never : unknown)>(o: T): void;
```

This is a recursive [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on the type parameter `T` (such self-referential constraints are known as [F-bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) and allow more expressive constraints where they are allowed) which amounts to "allow `T` if and only if the empty object type `{}` is *not* assignable to `T`".  If you can assign an empty object to `T`, then `T` should be rejected; if you cannot, then `T` should be accepted.

This is implemented by constraining `T` to the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) `{} extends T ? never : unknown`.  If `{} extends T` is true, then `{}` is assignable to `T`, and so the conditional type resolves to `never`, and so the constraint is `T extends never` which will not be met, and you'll get an error.  On the other hand, if `{} extends T` is false, then `{}` is not assignable to `T`, and so the conditional type resolves to `unknown`, and so the constraint is `T extends unknown`, which will essentially always be met, and you won't get an error.

Let's test it:

```
func("string")         // passes
func({})               // fails
func<{ x?: number }>({}) // fails
```

Looks good.  Since `{} extends string` is false, you can call `func("string")`.  But since `{} extends {}` is true and since `{} extends { x?: number}` is true, then you cannot call `func({})` or `func<{x?: number}>({})`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVLTAB4AVeEADwxFWAGd4AKAbwF9yqb74yB+eVCABuIGPABc8NAGtUOAO6oAlAD5GOSSSWShOLMADcAWABQplOkYAiOhhhZUAcytL4b9+4D0n+AAcodHQgdOaELKyuHlFR3khQWBAhJhbEzPAUvJKoyAC2AEai8KxqbK6xiPGJQA)

Comment: Appreciate the answer and the detailed explanation. Thanks @jcalz!